# CSS grid layout in a numerical order

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using CSS grid for a layout. Basically what I want to do is to have the items appear as a grid, but in numerical order. Take the example below:

```css
.list ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.list li {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
     <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Currently, the output of this is:

```
1-----2-----3
4-----5-----6
7-----8-----9
```

When I want:

```
1-----4-----7
2-----5-----8
3-----6-----9
```

Is there a way to do this with CSS grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `grid-template-columns` to:

```
grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
```

Then add this style:

```
grid-auto-flow: column;
```

**Snippet:**

```css
.list ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.list li {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
     <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok interesting! I needed in my specific instance outside the fiddle needed to add `grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);` to get the grid in the correct order.